# If $A = (4xy-3x^2z^2)i + 2x^2j - 2x^3zk$, prove that $\int_C A.dr$ is independent of the curve $C$ joining two given points.

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors

If $A = (4xy-3x^2z^2)i + 2x^2j - 2x^3zk$, prove that $\int_C A.dr$ is independent of the curve $C$ joining two given points.

Attempt

$\int_C A.dr=\int_C \{(4xy-3x^2z^2)dx + 2x^2dy - 2x^3zdz\}$

What to next? How to show it is independent of the curve $C$ joining two given points? Please help.

Comment: Do you know the connection between path independence of line integrals, conservative vector fields and potentials?

Comment: @Bernard8 Do you mean that if $Curl A=0$ then $\int_C A.dr$ is independent of the curve C joining two given points ?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by showing that the curl of the vector field $A$ is 0. You can then conclude that the vector field is conservative so line integrals are path independent.

Alternatively, you could show that $A$ is the gradient of some function, which you would need to find. If such a function exists then it follows that $A$ is conservative.

Comment: Note in general you also need the domain of the vector field to be simply connected. Here it doesn't matter since the vector field is well-defined and curl-free on all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (and so is globally integrable on any subregion).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi(x,y,z)=2x^2y-x^3z^2$. Then
$$\vec\nabla\phi=\vec A(x,y,z)=
(4xy-3x^2z^2)i + 2x^2j - 2x^3zk.$$
That means $\vec A$ is a [conservative vector field](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field) with scalar potential $\phi$ on any open subset $U$ of $\Bbb R^3$. Therefore, for any two points the start $S$ and the end $E$ in $U$, the path integral $$\int_S^E\vec A\cdot \vec{dr}=\int_C\vec A\cdot\vec{dr}$$
is independent of the  path $C$ taken from $S$ to $E$.

Note also that $\vec A$ is irrrotational, that is, it has a vanishing curl. This follows from the fact that the curl of a gradient is zero.